# ActionBar tabs--no page change

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I'm writing an Android app with Fragments, each represented by a ViewPager tab. MainActivity extends TabListener, and I have a ViewPager defined within it. Swiping left and right changes the active Fragment, as expected, but clicking on a tab in the ActionBar does not change the active Fragment.
I did some debugging, and it turns out that onTabSelected() is called on both swipes and ActionBar tab selection, but onPageSelected() is only called when swiping. I tried placing a ActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem call in onTabSelected, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make sure that when `onTabSelected` is called you set that tab as the `ViewPager`'s current item as -

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
}
```